Cosmological horizon and particle production
Typically, one studies particle production in de Sitter using a scalar field, and observing that one can rearrange the problem as one of a scalar field in Minkowski but with a time-dependent frequency (working on conformal time and with a rescaled field amplitude). From this picture, the phenomenon of particle production is just one of particles being created homogeneously and then propagating linearly in conformal time $\eta$. In principle, this propagation is not bounded. However, this contrasts with the fact that in the Sitter there is a horizon of radius $R_{h}=\frac{1}{H}$ that light should not be able to reach, not to mention particles which travel slower. Then, where is this horizon manifested in the problem of particle production?

I think the horizon sort of is the origin of these particles. This is the Unruh effect in curved spacetime: the stationary state in a spacetime with a bifurcate Killing horizon is thermal. I believe Wald's book discusses this around chapter 5. I never worked out the calculation in the way you mentioned, so I'm not fully sure, but check this out. It also goes by the name of Gibbons--Hawking effect

The horizon is manifest (or just something we have to deal with) in attempting to define a scattering matrix in de Sitter (dS) space. Recall that in typical S-matrix scattering, we can define an in-state and an out-state at asymptotic infinity. Ok, well what happens when we try to do the same thing but in dS space? We find that at asymptotic infinity when trying to define (or prepare when thinking about a lab experiment) well-defined in- and out-states that there is particle production due to gravitational effects at asymptotic infinity. The way we get around this is by writing down a state that comes in, but then leaves the same way but produces a noticeable affect during this time. This is the in-in formalism, and a more rigorous way is via the Schwinger-Keldysh formalism (which people usually relate to being the same, but they each have their advantage and disadvantage).
